# Replace Function in ADODB recordset VB6

Tags: vba, ms-access, vb6, adodb

From a visual basic application I have to **REPLACE** the value contained in a
column with another one.
 with **ADODB** I get that error:"**Undefined function Replace**"
I Uses **MS-ACCESS** Database in my **VB6** Application.
Is There any Way?

Comment: For the most part, you cannot use Replace with MS Access outside of MS Access itself. Post your sql and an alternative may be found.

Comment: @Remou my sql is "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE REPLACE(ITEM,'.','') LIKE 'FOODS A/C'"

Comment: Where does the stop that you are replacing occur in the string?

Comment: @Remou ITEM NAME IS 'FOODS A/C.'

Comment: Why do you need to replace the stop if you know where it is? If it is sometimes there and sometimes not, you can say `Item Like 'Foods A/C%'`

Comment: @Remou if i'll use Like 'Foods A/C%' then item with 'Food A/C Current' will also be in result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20949/discussion-between-chotai-mit-and-remou)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that something like this may suit:

```
 IIf(Right([item],1)=".",[item],[item] & ".") = 'FOODS A/C.'
```